# How to evaluate boolean expression at runtime using Compute method of Datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

If I do

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 var v = dt.Compute("3 * (2+4)", "");
```

it works fine.

But If I do

```
 var v1 = dt.Compute("true && true && false || false || false || true", "");
```

getting error at runtime

**Syntax error: Missing operand before '&' operator.**

What is that I am missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `AND` and `OR`:

```
bool b = (bool)dt.Compute("true AND true AND false OR false OR false OR true", "");
```

> Concatenation is allowed using Boolean `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT` operators. You
>   can use parentheses to group clauses and force precedence. The `AND`
>   operator has precedence over other operators.

You'll find a list of supported operators [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx).

Comment: Right...even i also did the same after looking into https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't use bool logic in DataTable like in C#. Try it this way:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var v = (bool)dt.Compute("true AND true AND false OR false OR false OR true", "");
```